# How can I Connect Github And Git with My VS Code and What It can Benefit me?

Tags: git, visual-studio, dart, github, visual-studio-code

I recently Got to Know about Git, Still not sure How it Works and Why should I connect it with My VS Code.
I feel it will be good for my Productivity if it can Benefit us, How To Set up Git with VS code?

Comment: The VScode docs are very good on this, read through them and then ask a specific question here if you are unsure on anything.  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/github  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol

Answer (score 0):

you can check the docs https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/github
and you can use extensions like **gitLens**
these tools can help you working with git easily specially if you are a beginner it will help you a lot and spare you the work with terminal ,,

until you figure out how to work with git in the terminal these extensions will help you do ***day to day work*** easily